# Save User to Firebase Database in Kotlin | Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

My problem is that I want save the uid, username and his profileImageUrl. All variables give the output that I need except "user" (I think).

**This is the function to save the user to database:**

```
private fun saveUserToFirebaseDatabase(profileImageUrl: String) {
                val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
                val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$uid")

                val user = User(uid, username_edittext_register.text.toString(), profileImageUrl)

                ref.setValue(user)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Finally we saved the user to Firebase Database")

                                val intent = Intent(this,LatestMessagesActivity::class.java)
                                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                                startActivity(intent)
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener{
                                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Failed to set value to database: ${it.message}")
                        }
                        Log.d("saveUserToDatabase","Task completed? User: $user")
        }
```

**This the class User:**

```
class User(val uid: String,val username: String,val profileImageUrl: String) {
        constructor() : this("", "", "")
}
```

**This is the "whole" code:**

```
package letsbuildthatapp.com

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_register.*
import java.util.*


class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)

                register_button_register.setOnClickListener {
                        performRegister()
                }

                already_have_account_text_view.setOnClickListener {
                        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Try to show login activity")

                        //Launch the login activity somehow
                        val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                }

                selectphoto_button_register.setOnClickListener {
                        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Try to show photo selector")

                        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
                        intent.type = "image/*"
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 0)
                }
        }

        var selectedPhotoUri: Uri? = null

        override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

                if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Photo was selected")

                        selectedPhotoUri = data.data

                        val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver,selectedPhotoUri)

                        select_photo_imageView_register.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                        selectphoto_button_register.alpha = 0f
                }
        }

        private fun performRegister() {
                val username = username_edittext_register.text.toString()
                val email = email_edittext_register.text.toString()
                val password = password_edittext_register.text.toString()

                if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter text in email/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        return
                }

                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Username: $username")
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Email is: $email")
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Password: $password")

                // Firebase Authentication to create a user with email and password
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener{
                if (!it.isSuccessful) return@addOnCompleteListener

                        //else if successful
                        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Successfully created user with uid: ${it.result.user!!.uid}")
                                uploadImageToFirebaseStorage()
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener{
                                Log.d("RegisterActivity","Failed to create user: ${it.message}")
                                Toast.makeText(this,"Failed to create user: ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                }

        private fun uploadImageToFirebaseStorage() {
                if (selectedPhotoUri == null) return

                val filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/images/$filename")

                ref.putFile(selectedPhotoUri!!)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Successfully uploaded image: ${it.metadata?.path}")

                                ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                                        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "File Location: $it")

                                        saveUserToFirebaseDatabase(it.toString())
                                }
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener{
                                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Failed")
                                Toast.makeText(this,"Failed: ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
        }

        private fun saveUserToFirebaseDatabase(profileImageUrl: String) {
                val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
                val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$uid")

                val user = User(uid, username_edittext_register.text.toString(), profileImageUrl)

                ref.setValue(user)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Finally we saved the user to Firebase Database")

                                val intent = Intent(this,LatestMessagesActivity::class.java)
                                intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                                startActivity(intent)
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener{
                                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Failed to set value to database: ${it.message}")
                        }
                        Log.d("saveUserToDatabase","Task completed? User: $user")
        }
}

class User(val uid: String,val username: String,val profileImageUrl: String) {
        constructor() : this("", "", "")
}
```

This is the output of "user": letsbuildthatapp.com.User@41cb40

Comment: What do you mean by "except "user" (I think)"? Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Going forward, please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution for this Problem. It's really simple and making me sad that I get now after a day.

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Type here the Url of the database!).getReference("/users/$uid")
```